# Why remove delete everything?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Why If do I take off the comment the page doesn't show P elements anymore?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        <!--
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var $p = $("div > p:last-child");
                $p.clone().attr("nome", "p_" + i).text("nome p_" + i).appendTo($p);

                /*
                if (i == 9) {
                    $("div > p:first-child").remove();
                }
                */
            }
        //-->
    </script>
```

Comment: what do you expect from this code? i.e. the expected output

Comment: put all p by code and remove the first p.

Comment: rather than using words, please put an example output in your question body

Comment: Without comment:

""
content

nome p_0

nome p_1

nome p_2

nome p_3

nome p_4

nome p_5

nome p_6

nome p_7

nome p_8

nome p_9
""

With = nothing

Answer (score 1):

Your `div` always has only one immediate `p` child, which you append other `p` elements to.

So these are always identical:

```
$("div > p:last-child");
$("div > p:first-child");
```

When you do this:

```
$("div > p:first-child").remove();
```

… you've essentially removed everything appended to:

```
$("div > p:last-child");
```

If you *don't* want this behavior, then append the new `p` elements to the `div` itself:

```
$p.clone().attr("nome", "p_" + i).text("nome p_" + i).appendTo('div');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ygxdckv/)

Comment: Good Explanation for a beginner :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're appending the clones of the first paragraph to the first paragraph - which is the only direct child of the div; so when you remove the last-child, it's really the same as the first, and removes all of the other nested clones. Try appending to the div instead.

```
$p.clone().attr("nome", "p_"+i).text("nome p_"+i).appendTo('div');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c41s1b0z/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation on appendTo: http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

You are adding content **inside** your paragraph, not after it.

```
<p>content [appended paragraphs are going here]</p>
```

Then you are selecting the paragraph and removing it. If you want to remove the first paragraph inside the content paragraph you'd need to change your selector to

```
div>p>p:first-child
```

Answer (score 0):

With or without the comment, the page is rendering exactly the same for me.

Comment: So doesn't the p with "content" disappear?

For me without comment disappear everything.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and should have been posted as a comment

Comment: I mean when i decommend the if and put it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **append**  not **appendTo**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var $p = $("div > p:last-child");
    $('div').append($p.clone().attr("nome", "p_" + i).text("nome p_" + i));
    if (i == 9) {
        $("div > p").first().remove();
        //$("div > p:first-child").remove()
    }
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pn015k6m/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to wveryone I solved in this way:

```
var $p = $("div>p:last-child");
    $p.clone().attr("nome", "p_"+i).text("nome p_"+i).insertAfter($p);
    if (i==9) {$("div>p:first-child").remove();
```

The last code put p dinamically genereted in th first p.